# React Forms- onSubmit is not being called, tried other solutions to no avail

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I'm creating a simple component on React that can take users input, to later display it,it renders a form, an input text field, and a button.

The problem is that the handleSubmit function is never called, even if I placed an arrow function directly in the onSubmit to just prevent the page from reloading or just to log that the button was pushed on the console, it's like it's not calling the onSubmit property, but it does reload the page.

I tried a response indicating to add the code below to the constructor, with no changes, I'm not sure what else to try, without just getting rid of the form and using onClick.

```
this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
```

This is my code:

```
class ToDoListDisplay extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {

    };
  }
  render(){
  return (
      <div>
        <h3>Tasks</h3>
        <TaskForm />
        <div>

        </div>
      </div>  

    );
  } 
}

class InputField extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {userInputTitle: ''};
  }


  render(){
    return(
      <input 
        type="text"
        placeholder="New Task title..."
        value={this.state.userInputTitle}
        onChange={event => this.setState({userInputTitle: event.target.value})}

      />
    );
  }

}

class AddButton extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <button type="submit" >Add</button>
    );
  }
}


class TaskForm extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tasks: [],      
    }
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('Botton pushed');
    //this.setState();
  }  
  render(){
    return(
    <div>
      <form
       onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
       id="taskForm"
      >
        <InputField />
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )}
}
```

Comment: try `onsubmit` - case sensitive

Comment: Form `onSubmit` works fine here in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/old-forest-yc2q3?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js&theme=dark)

Comment: I'll try, but all examples I could find used ```onSubmit```

Comment: Other events are not triggered either.
however when I tried on jscomplete/playground, it works fine.
It seems to be caused by the dev environment not translating onSubmit as a prop, gonna have to look into it.